# Return a List of Member Variables from a List of Objects?

Tags: python

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
foos = []
foos.append(Foo(1))
foos.append(Foo(2))
foos.append(Foo(3))
```

Aside from:

```
bar_list = []
for foo in foos:
    bar_list.append(foo.bar)
```

Is there any pythonic way to extract a list of `bar`s from a list of `Foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[foo.bar for foo in foos]
```

Comment: This is also usually the answer for getting a list of anything from a list of anything else.